# index out of bounds while copying one image into a region of another

Tags: matlab, image-processing, indexoutofboundsexception

Can somebody help me fix this index out of bounds error in that happens when calcification_image into a region of contour_image located around the center ??
The code is in matlab

```
function [final_image] = addCalcificationToContour(contour_image, calcification_image)
final_image=contour_image;
calcificationI=1;
calcificationJ=1;
contour_image_size=size(contour_image)
calcification_image_size=size(calcification_image)
    for finalImageI=int32(size(contour_image,2)/2)-size(calcification_image,2)/2:int32(size(contour_image,2)/2+size(calcification_image,2)/2)-1
        calcificationI=calcificationI+1;
        calcificationJ=1;
        for finalImageJ=int32(size(contour_image,1)/2)-size(calcification_image,1)/2:int32(size(contour_image,1)/2+size(calcification_image,1)/2)-1

            final_image(finalImageI,finalImageJ)=calcification_image(calcificationI,calcificationJ);

            calcificationJ=calcificationJ+1;
        end
    end
figure;imshow(calcification_image);
end
```

**The error message produced is the following:**

> Attempted to access calcification_image(241,1); index out of bounds
>   because size(calcification_image)=[240,305,3].
>
> Error in addCalcificationToContour (line 12)
>               final_image(finalImageI,finalImageJ)=calcification_image(calcificationI,calcificationJ);

Comment: 1) You don't need a loop to do that. 2) The error message means that in the definition of your loop you are, at some point, making calcificationI = 241, and that image is only 240 pixels across. 3) In addition `calcification_image` appears to be RGB which your code is not set up to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the errors by rewriting the code... 
Not only I did not handle RGB Colours, I had also used inverse row and column coordinates...